# How can I achieve HtmlContainer functionality in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In webforms, I can make my class inherit `HtmlContainer` and then I can insert HTML into usercontrols of that class. something like this:

```
<cc:Container1><p>hello world!</p></cc:Container1>
```

How can I achieve the same functionality in Razor? I mean something like this:

```
@Html.Gadget(type: Nested){ </p>hello world!</p> }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [inline helpers](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/04/dissecting-razor-part-9-inline-helpers.html):

```
@Html.Gadget(@<p>...</p>)
```

Comment: Thanks SLaks. This is a nice workaround; but not exactly what I meant. Perhaps I'd better say I need a helper that is used like a `for(...) { }` block...

Comment: @Achilles: I'm not sure what you mean.  Except that this is passed inside the argument list, this should be perfect for you.  You can call the inline helper multiple times within the function.

Comment: Well, excuse me if I were unclear. I know I can achieve the same functionality of passing HTML to a helper using inline helpers; but I'm wondering whether I can create a helper that accepts a `{...}` delegate; exactly like a `for (...)` block does.
I mean accepting a delegate but not as a parameter...

Comment: @Achilles: No; that's not possible.  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I think if I write my Views' code like this, It will be much easier to read in the future.
I think I can achieve this functionality, only by extending the MVC/Razor source and creating a custom View-Engine...
Thank you for sharing your knowledge with us :)